# App crashes when transitioning between tabs, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I could use some help debugging this issue if anyone has had experience with it.  I have a UITabBarController as my root view controller.  The first view controllers of each tab are UINavigationController.

Tab 1:
A view with a map is the first viewController.
When you push on the callout, this code is run:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLocationDetails" sender:self];
}
```

In the storyboard, I have this wired up as `Push`.

On the first viewController, because I have a map and don't want to have a navigation bar show, I do this:

```
FirstViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

On the second view controller that I push onto the stack, I do want the navigation bar, so I have this code:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]]) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Tab 2:
Just a tablview for right now.

I can get my app to crash if I do these simple steps:

Press the callout to push the LocationDetails.
Press back to go back to First View Controller
Press tab two to go to a TableViewController
Press tab one to go back to the map and this crashes it with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I tried running Instruments, but I didn't know what it meant:

[image]

If I start the app, and just switch between the tabs all day without pushing a new controller onto the stack on tab 1, it does NOT crash.

It also does not crash if I remove the navigationController willShowViewController delegate methods.  But of course then I have the navigation bar which is not what I want.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

**EDITED**
So I tried what Nuzhat said and I get the same problem.  I tried both

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

and

```
self.navigationController.navigationBardHidden = YES;
```

and it isn't the solution I"m looking for.  What happens is when I push to the next view controller the navigationBar is not there.  So in that viewController's viewDidLoad, I set

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

Then I pop back to FirstViewController, then I switch tabs, still crashes.  There seems to be a problem with hiding the navigation bar, and then showing it again.

Comment: If you do not want to show navigation controller in your first view controller, then just add     self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES; where you are initializing your view.

Comment: +1 to @NuzhatZari, you really don't want all of your "child" view controllers to be setup as delegates of your nav controller.

Comment: @Nuzhat Zari That doesn't work.  I added more information into my question regarding your suggestion.